# Subset a data frame and store to different variables in R using loop or lapply

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I want to subset it several times and store it in different variable names. Let's say my data frame looks something like this:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(5)
y <- rnorm(5)
z <- rnorm(5)

f1 <- gl(2,1, labels = c("good", "bad"), length =5)
f2 <- gl(3,1, labels = c("red", "green", "yellow"), length = 5)
f3 <- gl(5,1, labels = c("foo", "bar", "foobar", "foofoo", "barbar"))

df <- data.frame(x,y,z,f1,f2,f3)    
> df

            x          y          z   f1     f2     f3
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818 good    red    foo
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  bad  green    bar
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 good yellow foobar
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  bad    red foofoo
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 good  green barbar
```

What I want to do is to create three new data frames by subsetting df and store them to different variable names. I know how to do that individually:

```
df_f1 <- df[,c(-5,-6)]

> df_f1
            x          y          z   f1
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818 good
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  bad
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 good
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  bad
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 good

df_f2 <- df[,c(-4,-6)]

> df_f2
            x          y          z     f2
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818    red
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  green
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 yellow
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827    red
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411  green

df_f3 <- df[,c(-4,-5)]
> df_f3
            x          y          z     f3
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818    foo
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138    bar
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 foobar
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827 foofoo
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 barbar
```

However, is there a way to do it programmatically? Maybe using a for loop or lapply? My problem is that I don't know how can I assign the data frames I need to different variable names such as df_f1, df_f2 and df_f3 automatically without manually typing them one by one. What I mean is, is there a way to automatically generate variable names so that I can store data frames on them using loop or lapply?

I will apply this concept to a bigger data set and manually typing each variable names is quite tedious.

Thanks and have a nice day to all!

Comment: what do you want to do after assigning so many variables? it is most like better to store them as 1 data.frame and continue working on it rather than have many data.frames. but if you really really want to have so many variables and then have to type them one by one again, you can use `assign`

Comment: @chinsoon12 I want to create a predictive model for each data.frame having the last column as my target and the rest of my data as inputs. What I mean is, is there a way to generate variable names automatically so I can store my data.frames using loop or lapply?

Comment: @timcheen14 - you don't need to store the whole dataset for that. You can just store the formula you want to use for your model, and update that and keep `df` as it is. E.g. (excusing a nonsense model): `frm <- f3 ~ .; lm(frm, data=df)`

Comment: to generalize `lapply(paste0("f", 1:3), function(f) lm(as.formula(paste(f, "~ .")), data=df))`

Comment: @thelatemail Oh I see. Okay will try to do that. Thanks chinsoon12 and thelatemail. Though for curiosity's sake, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(df[-(1:3)],cbind,df[1:3]),paste("df",1:3,sep="_f")),.GlobalEnv)
```

Breakdown:

First create a list that you need that has all the dataframes.

```
  A=lapply(df[-(1:3)],cbind,df[1:3])
```

This takes all the other columns appart from 1:3, and then cbinds each one of the columns with `df[1:3]`. This gives me a list A that hass all the dataframes I need.
Now Give every dataframe in the list A name:

```
  B=setNames(A,paste("df",1:3,sep="_f"))
```

You can play with `paste` to see how it combines two things together. 
After that. We will list each element of the list, which is technically a dataframe to our global environment.

```
 list2env(B,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This seems to work but I don't easily comprehend what happens with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, using `lapply` :

```
keep<-3
split_id<-(keep+1):length(df)
df_list<- lapply(split_id, function(x){
  df[,c(1:3,x)]
})

df_list
[[1]]
            x          y          z   f1
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818 good
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  bad
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 good
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  bad
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 good

[[2]]
            x          y          z     f2
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818    red
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  green
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 yellow
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827    red
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411  green

[[3]]
            x          y          z     f3
1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818    foo
2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138    bar
3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 foobar
4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827 foofoo
5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 barbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```r
dependent_col = c("f1", "f2", "f3")
df_l <- lapply(dependent_col, function(x) df[!(colnames(df) %in% dependent_col) | colnames(df) == x])
names(df_l) <- paste("df", dependent_col, sep="_")
df_l
```

You can access individual dataframe using `df_l$df_f1`, `df_l$df_f2` etc...